# How to get promise result in this case

Tags: javascript, promise, resolve

I must fill a table with the data that I bring from the call to an api, after this call another api (QRCODES) to generate a Qr image with that data.

the problem is that in the resulting array to pass to the table the field where the address to the image should go (qr code) I am getting a "promise" object

```
    const setTable = async () => {
        console.log(selectedChannel);
        productsService.getProducts(selectedChannel.name, selectedCategory.id).then(data => {
            setProducts(data.data)
            const dataTable = []
            const allArray = data.data
            console.log(allArray)
            let row = {}
            let link = ''
            let qrImage = ''


            allArray.forEach(product => {
                link = "https://motitools.deco.cl/" + selectedChannel.name + "/es-CL/products/" + product.slug
                qrImage = QRCode.toDataURL(link)
                row =  { "imagenQr": qrImage, "category": product.category, "name": product.name, "price": product.price, "image": product.image }
                dataTable.push(row)
            });
            console.log(dataTable)
            setTableConten(dataTable)
        });
```

The result of **qrImage = QRCode.toDataURL(link)**

```
imagenQr: Promise
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAL
```

> how can i get the value of **[[PromiseResult]]**?.

Usefull info:
1.- make: qrImage = **await** QRCode.toDataURL(link) gives me this error
[image: console error]

2.- make **QRCode.toDataURL(link).then( data => console.log(data))** return all the codes in console, how set a variable with this value ?

[image]

im new on javascript

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. "_

Comment: _"im new on javascript"_ - Then don't rely on [ASI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi) and always use semicolons

Comment: @Andreas I'll include the tips next time, thanks for the critique

Comment: Not _"next time"_. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73460917/edit) your question now.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use `await`, but not in the non `async` callback. Mixing `then` with `async` is rarely a good idea. So drop the `.then` call, and use `await` instead, and make the inner callback `async`.

Some other remarks:

- The `.forEach()` + `push` pattern is better replaced with `.map()` which returns the desired array.
- I'd also use some destructuring assignments to simplify some code.
- Use semicolons to separate your statements.
- Don't declare variables with a larger scope than needed (like `row`, `link`, `qrImage`,...)

```
const setTable = async () => {
    const {data} = await productsService.getProducts(selectedChannel.name, selectedCategory.id);
    setProducts(data);

    const dataTable = await Promise.all(data.map(async ({slug, category, name, price, image}) => {
        const link = "https://motitools.deco.cl/" + selectedChannel.name + "/es-CL/products/" + slug
        const qrImage = await QRCode.toDataURL(link);
        return { "imagenQr": qrImage, category, name, price, image };
    }));
    setTableConten(dataTable);
};
```